# Python Submit post and get results

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape store locations from aeropostal webpage but the way i am doing it it seems that it doesnt work, can someone guide me? or tell me what i am doing wrong? here is my code:

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'http://www.aeropostale.com/storeLocator/index.jsp'
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(response)
    # {'city': '', 'searchType': 'POSTAL_CODE', 'typeId': '0', 'findByZip': None, 'action': 'SEARCH_FOR_STORES', 'state': '', 'radius': '5', 'postalCode': None}
    html = fromstring(response.content)
    payload = dict(html.forms[2].fields)
    print(payload)
    # {'city': '', 'searchType': 'STATE', 'typeId': '0', 'findByZip': None, 'action': 'SEARCH_FOR_STORES', 'state': 'LA', 'radius': '50', 'postalCode': None}
    payload.update(({'searchType': 'STATE', 'state': 'LA', 'radius': '50'}))
    print(payload)
    locations = c.post(url, data=payload)
    print(locations)
    r = c.get('http://www.aeropostale.com/storeLocator/results.jsp')
    print(BeautifulSoup(r.content).text)
```

It doesnt get the posted result i dont know why and when i try to find the form of http://www.aeropostale.com/storeLocator/results.jsp
 it doesnt seems to have the posted form it gives me this form

```
# {'emailPrefAERO': 'Y', 'surveyOnly': 'Y', 'emailAddress': None, 'isSMS': 'N'}
```

can someone help me out?

Comment: Why do you ignore the `c.post()` response?

Comment: You use `c.post(url, data=payload)` but don't look at what the server responded. You then do a new `GET` request, but that's independant and doesn't have your search request anymore.

Comment: @MartijnPieters could you help me a bit more i dont really undestand what you are tying to tell me, i just started a week ago with python :/

Comment: Looking at that form, I see you either search for a store with a zipcode and a radius, *or* for a city in a state. You cannot pick a state and a radius, but no city and no zipcode.

Comment: @MartijnPieters look this image http://oi58.tinypic.com/v82d0g.jpg as you can see it doesnt need to be filled up and it would let me to pick state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are posting your query to the wrong location, then ignoring the response. Don't use a separate `GET` for the `results.jsp` page.

Post to the `results.jsp` location instead:

```
locations = c.post(
    'http://www.aeropostale.com/storeLocator/results.jsp',
    data=payload)
print(BeautifulSoup(locations.content).text)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from lxml.html import fromstring
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> c = requests.Session()
>>> url = 'http://www.aeropostale.com/storeLocator/index.jsp'
>>> response = requests.get(url)
>>> html = fromstring(response.content)
>>> payload = dict(html.forms[2].fields)
>>> payload.update({'searchType': 'STATE', 'state': 'LA', 'radius': '50'})
>>> payload
{'city': '', 'searchType': 'STATE', 'typeId': '0', 'findByZip': None, 'action': 'SEARCH_FOR_STORES', 'state': 'LA', 'radius': '50', 'postalCode': None}
>>> locations = c.post('http://www.aeropostale.com/storeLocator/results.jsp', data=payload)
>>> s = BeautifulSoup(locations.content)
>>> s.find('p', class_='location')
<p class="location">We found <strong>14 stores</strong> 


            within <strong>LA


</strong></p>
```